# Why is there an index error when the range condition is fulfilled?

Tags: python

here is the code that I want to run but it returns an index error: string index out of range at the "for val in oxy_val: segment.
if val[num] == '0':"

```
lines = ['110011110101','110011100010','010100011010','011001100000','010011011101','011110111000']
oxy_val = lines.copy()
while len(oxy_val) > 1:
    for num in range(12):
        ones = 0
        zeroes = 0
        for val in oxy_val:
            if val[num] == '0':
                zeroes+=1
            elif val[num] == '1':
                    ones+=1
        if zeroes > ones:
            oxy_val = [val[num] for val in oxy_val if val[num] == '0']
        elif ones > zeroes or ones == zeroes:
            oxy_val = [val[num] for val in oxy_val if val[num] == '1']
            
print(oxy_val)
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: A first step would be to `print(val, num)` immediately before that line…

Comment: The error  obviously happens because you are trying to iterate 12 times a list of of 6 elements. Probably your outer for loop should be "for val in oxy_val", and the inner, "for num in range(12)" , but that depends on what you want to do, which you haven't stated in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If *num* is a positive integer (or zero) used as an index for a list L then it must be 0 <= num < len(L). Negative indexes are permitted in Python but not applicable here